# How to restrict function to only callable from one external contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, security, modifiers

I have a `Reputation` contract which has a function `foo()` that sets some point.

In another contract called `Market` I want to use the `foo()` function. But I don't want any one to be able to call `foo()` outside `Market`.

the problem is I need to deploy `Reputation` first and make instance of it in market. I have no idea how to make modifier in `Reputation` to restrict `foo()` before deploying `Market`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `msg.sender` and reject unacceptable actors.

In `Market` to protect `foo()` - make sure `msg.sender == reputation`.

Also in `Market` - a function to update `reputation` when you know the address.

Here's a little scribble to give you some ideas.

```
contract Market {

  address reputation;

  modifier onlyReputation {
    require(msg.sender == reputation, "403");
    _;
  }

  constructor(address reputation_) {
    reputation = reputation_;
  }

  function foo() public onlyReputation {
    // carry on
  }
}
```

That is the general idea. You can add functions to edit/update the acceptable `reputation` from time to time. You would want another variable, e.g. `address owner` to specify who is allowed to do that.

Finally, if you want to coordinate the deployment and there is one Market for each Reputation, use the `constructors` to configure everything on the fly.

In `Reputation`:

```
Market market;);

constructor () {
   market = new Market();
}
```

That way it will create one and know where it is. In `Market`, recognize "the creator" as the one to trust.

```
address reputation;

constructor () {
  reputation = msg.sender;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: this is the opposite of what I was looking for. I needed a modifier called onlyMarket. But thanks, your answer gave me the idea how to do that. All I wanted to need was to initiate market with some address and then update the market address in reputation contract using some other functions. :)